# Execute code at React native iOS module initialization

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

When writing a native module for Android (extending `ReactContextBaseJavaModule`), I can easily add some code to be run once when the module is created (in the constructor for example).

When writing a native module for iOS, where can I put such code? I need to call an init method on some custom SDK I use...

I don't see anything where I could hookup in [RCTBridgeModule](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h)

Comment: I have found the answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49128158/initialisation-for-react-native-rctbridgemodule). Sorry for the duplicate...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initialisation for react-native RCTBridgeModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49128158/initialisation-for-react-native-rctbridgemodule)